How to Load Personal .bash_rc for SU User via Direct SSH command
Problem
Multiple engineers are using same machine with same loginuser and history gets loaded with others' people commands.
Update: People login via private ssh keys (pub added/removed via trustedhosr). Admin user is only one and we cannot add more.

Connecting via ssh using ssh key as regular user
ssh -t loginuser@some-hostname
Running SOME-HOSTNAME loginuser ~ ❯ su adminuser
Runing various commands and history gets filled


Solution

Create personal .bashrc file and set personal HISTFILE path.
Use customized ssh command

Steps
Prepare Personal .bashrc
mkdir /home/adminuser/bash_rc/ 
mkdir /home/adminuser/bash_histories/ 

Create/Edit File
nano /home/adminuser/bash_rc/.bashrc_vladimir

Add Content and Save
# .bashrc
# User specific environment
PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH

HISTFILE=$HOME/bash_histories/vladimir/.bash_history
export HISTFILE

# User specific aliases and functions
PS1="\[\033[01;31m\]VLADIMIR@SOME-HOSTNAME \[\033[01;32m\]\u \[\033[01;34m\]\W \[\033[01;35m\]>\[\033[00m\] "

Run custom ssh command
ssh -t loginuser@SOME-HOSTNAME 'su - adminuser --session-command "bash --rcfile /home/adminuser/bash_rc/.bashrc_vladimir"'


ssh -t Force pseudo-terminal allocation.
su - adminuser --session-command any command, here bash is used
bash --rcfile /home/adminuser/bash_rc/.bashrc_vladimir" tell bash to use personal .bashrc file


use sudo -u adminuser, and connect each sysadmin to his dedicated account! So you will be able to deluser simply, when required!

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub we are sharing one user unfortunately... (Don't ask) Will update my question with this info. Thanks!

How do you prevent someone else using .bashrc_vladimir ?

Use only 1 account to be shared, but through sudo! Add one user account for EACH remote sysadmin access to NOT be shared!! ( Keep in mind, the financial cost for 1 user account is alway the same, regarding licensing too! ;-) In other word: Don't do this!

@Philippe it is not about preventing. I personally don't care and I find this useful. I am looking forward to see other answers that can be useful as well. Thanks

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub question was how to do this not how to add additional users. Adding more users is not an option - it is how it is
